# Laravel eloquent table-less data from external source

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, eloquent, relationship

I'm developing an application where my data comes from external server in JSON format.

I would like to set a relationships between each models, but without using a database table.

**Is it possible ?**

Something like that:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'https://.../server/flights.json';
}
```

Comment: Why not make a "service" class which gets data from the api and use a "factory" to instantiate models?

Comment: with this code sample I think you are way in the wrong way! A service set up

Comment: could you please provide any link to a good source where I can get more information about ? Is it a SERVICE CONTAINER you are talking about ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a service class which handles the request and returns class instances:

```
namespace App\Services;

class FlightService
{
    /**
    * @var FlightFactory
    */
    private $flightFactory;

    public function __construct(FlightFactory $flightFactory)
    {
        $this->flightFactory = $flightFactory;
    }

    public function getAllFlights()
    {
        $flightsJson = $this->getFromExternalCurl();
        return $this->flightFactory->buildFlightList($flightsJson);
    }

    private function getFromExternalCurl()
    {
        return Curl::to('http://www.foo.com/flights.json')
        ->withData( array( 'foz' => 'baz' ) )
        ->asJson()
        ->get();
    }

}
```

Basically the service would make the external API call and the response is passed to a factory which creates the instances.

Note that you just need to add the factory in the construct and it's binded because laravel uses https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container

```
namespace App\Factories;

class FlightFactory
{
    public function buildFlightList($flightJsonList)
    {
        $flightCollection = collect();
        foreach($flightJsonList as $flightJson) {
            $flightCollection->push($this->buildFlight($flightJson));
        }
        return $flightCollection;
    }

    public function buildFlight($flightJson)
    {
        $flight = new Flight();
        // add properties
        return $flight;
    }

}
```

The factory will return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) which is verry usefull because it contains usefull methods, or you can return an array.

In this example I used a curl library https://github.com/ixudra/curl but it can be replaced with native php or other libraries.

Then you can use by injecting the `FlightService` in your controllers.

P.S: Code not tested but represents a possible approach

Comment: Thank you ka_lin! I'm trying to implement your suggestion. I will give my feedback afterwards.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but How should I connect it, so Model's method such as belongsTo, hasMany would be accepted ?

Comment: Those are ORM specific and you did say you don't want to use DB, do you want to get data from the API store it, process it and display it OR just get and show?

Comment: those data comes from external server in real-time via API, without having to store them in internal application DB.
Is it possible you think?